# MySQL wont run on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS under WSL

Tags: server, 20.04, mysql, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been going round and round trying to solve the below issue when trying to start MySQL:

```
2022-01-27T09:47:14.547946Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010139] [Server] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 8161)
2022-01-27T09:56:22.047681Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010142] [Server] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 4000) 
...
2022-01-27T09:56:22.265005Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
```

I've tried upping my `limits.conf` file values, and in `/etc/service` however those values are all over 10000 (or in some cases 65535) however no matter what I change when I run:

`ulimit -Sa | grep "open files"`

The result is always:

`open files                      (-n) 1024`

Any help would be appreciated but I just can't see any other solutions?

I have no databases yet, I've not even managed to boot MySQL to log in once.

MySQL is Ver 8.0.27
Running on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on WSL

Comment: Could you elaborate on what problem you're trying to solve? Do you have a database (or many databases) with thousands of tables? Are you running on a server with less than 1GB RAM? Which version of MySQL are you using? Does the DB use InnoDB or MyISAM? How is `mysql.cnf` configured? There's a lot that can cause the sort of problems expressed in your question ... 

Comment: I am literally trying to get a fresh install of MySQL server to run, I've no databases at all yet. I'm using WSL (as per my tag) - my mysql.cnf is out of the box, I've not changed it.

Comment: Have you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54649885/12289283) ?

Comment: Yes, my LimitNOFILE is set to 10000 by default in that file. I've set it to 65535 in `etc\systemd\system\mysqld.service.d\limits.conf`

Comment: You wouldn’t happen to be running Node services in the same WSL container, would you? 

Comment: I have node installed yes (working to have a WP vhost set up with Sage 10 which uses npm)

Comment: Yeah, Node is really good at making simple things hard. Does `sudo sh -c "ulimit -n 65535 && exec su $LOGNAME"` give you a proper working environment? Alternatively, running this setup in a VirtualBox VM would be a good way to avoid the arbitrary limits imposed by WSL 

Comment: @Aravona How are you starting mysql?

Comment: @Aravona Also, the more information you can give me on your current set-up the better.  I'm happy to try to solve it.  Right now, I know *why* `limits.conf` and other settings aren't working the way you'd expect (lack of PAM and Systemd support on WSL).  I'm sure there's a workaround, but I need to be able to reproduce your problem before I can propose a solution, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

WSL does not have `systemd`. That is why your changes from `/etc/systemd/system/mysqld.service.d/limits.conf` are not applied. So `ulimit -n` returns `1024`.

You can edit the `/etc/security/limits.conf` file in order to increase the limits for every user by appending the following lines:

```
* soft nofile 10000
* hard nofile 10000
```

By restarting `mysql` service, the above file is read an applied. In order to restart `mysql` service execute:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

The limits will be changed for user `mysql`. To check this you can run the command:

```
ps -ef|grep -e ^mysql
mysql       90     1  0 18:28 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
mysql      250    90  0 18:28 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --log-error=/var/log/mysql/error.log --pid-file=statie-ac-0027.pid

for pid in `ps -ef|grep -e ^mysql|awk '{print $2}'` ; do echo pid=$pid user=`ps -ef|awk '{if( $2 == '$pid' ) print $1}'`; sudo prlimit -p $pid --nofile ; done

pid=90 user=mysql
RESOURCE DESCRIPTION               SOFT  HARD UNITS
NOFILE   max number of open files 10000 10000 files
pid=250 user = mysql
RESOURCE DESCRIPTION               SOFT  HARD UNITS
NOFILE   max number of open files 10000 10000 files
```

P.S.

It seems that for the normal user we have the same status (no change read for no file limit) because by default no login is executed. But if you run:

```
su <username>
```

then the limit files are read and `ulimit -n` will return `10000` also for the current user.

P.P.S.

My answer was inspired by:

- [How can I raise the limit for open files in Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63960859/how-can-i-raise-the-limit-for-open-files-in-ubuntu-20-04-on-wsl2)
- [Open file descriptor limits not updating or being overridden #1576](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1576#issuecomment-643804974)